# javascript update parent html

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to update the innerHTML of a div tag that's within the parent window from within an iframe.  How do I access the parent window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`window.parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.parent). Note, however, that you can only manipulate the parent document if it belongs to the same domain.

Comment: `window.parent.getElementById('last-updated').innerHTML = 'Last updated: ';` is not a function.... any ideas why?

Comment: @Webnet: It should be `window.parent.document`